# CSS styling html form

Tags: html, css, forms

I've got a php form and would like to add some css so that the HTML email isn't boring plain text.

```
     $msg  = "<h2><strong>EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM</strong></h2><br>" . 
  PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "your website<br>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------<br><br>" . 
  PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Name: </strong>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$name <br>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Email: </strong>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$email <br>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Contact Number: </strong>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$phone <br>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Day in: </strong>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$dayin <br>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Day out: </strong>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$dayout <br><br>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "<strong>Notes / Comments: </strong><br>" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

How can I make the "EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM" a different color / font?
I've tried `<span style="color:#FF0000;">EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM</span>` and that doesn't work

My Headers:

```
    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
```

I'm not sure if anything needs changing in the headers?

Also, at the top of my contact.php file is `if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");`
Must this stay the same?

---

EDIT

```
  $msg = "<html><body>
     <strong>EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM</strong><br>
     your website<br>
     ------------------------------------------------------<br><br>
     <strong>Name: </strong>
     $name <br>
     <strong>Email: </strong>
     $email <br>
     <strong>Contact Number: </strong>
     $phone <br>
     <strong>Day in: </strong>
     $dayin <br>
     <strong>Day out: </strong>
     $dayout <br><br>
     <strong>Notes / Comments: </strong><br>
     $comments
     </body></html>";
```

Comment: Note; for the sake of readability, you might consider using a **heredoc**, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

I found an example for sending emails with css here:
http://css-tricks.com/2866-sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

hope it solves your problem :).

Comment: Thanks ... I've read that article before, though every form seems to be coded differently and it usually never works out the same if I just copied their work. So I'm just focusing on MY form at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Augh, the code...

Okay, the short(est) answer is:

```
<strong style="color:#FF0000">.....</strong>
```

Will work for anything. Slightly better, and supported by most e-mail clients, is to use some inline styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .important { color: #ff0000; }
</style>

<strong class="important">....</strong>
```

This will do the same thing, and now if you want to make something else red later, or if you want to change important things to be orange, you have a single place you can change that.

Finally, with regards to the PHP part... you don't need all those newlines. HTML is whitespace-insensitive, so all they're doing is making your source code prettier. A better format would be something like this:

```
<?php
  $msg = <<<MESSAGE
  <h2><strong>EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM</strong></h2><br />
  <strong>Name: </strong> $name<br />
  <strong>Email: </strong> $email<br />
  ... etc ...
MESSAGE;
?>
```

This uses PHP "heredoc" format. You can learn more about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Hi, Thanks I've coded my HTML much better (see EDIT in my question above).
I've tried doing <strong style="color:#FF0000">.....</strong> and it doesn't work for some reason. I've been doing this before I even posted this question but I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: Is it possible that there's another CSS rule that is clobbering the color? What e-mail client are you viewing your result in?

Comment: I doubt it is my email client which is Windows Mail (vista) because I receive html emails on a daily basis. Nothing to do with my headers? Nothing to do with if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");?

Comment: Where do I put this: <style type="text/css">
  .important { color: #ff0000; }
</style>
?? Between <html> and <body>

Comment: "MIME-Version: 1.0" or "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" ?
... and whats better charset=utf-8 or charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the "EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM" a different color / font? I've tried EMAIL SUBMISSION FROM and that doesn't work

`color:FF0000` should be `color:#FF0000`.

> I'm not sure if anything needs changing in the headers?

Headers seem fine.

> Also, at the top of my contact.php file is if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n"); Must this stay the same?

Yes, this is fine.

Comment: Guide for CSS support in popular web and desktop e-mail clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Hi, thanks ... I know sorry typo error #FF0000 (changed in edit)